# How can we program statet to use both knitr and pdflatex

Tags: r, knitr, statet

In the new version of statet4.0, I would like to find a way to configure sweave to run with both knitr and pdflatex.

In external tool configuration > sweave Document processing there an example of using `tools::texi2dvi(file= "${resource_loc}", pdf= TRUE)` how should I configure to use pdflatex ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Latex document

I've set R Weave configuration to produce a `tex` (not `.tex`just tex)
[image: R Weave configuration]
Then I've used

```
system2(command='pdflatex', args=c('-interaction=nonstopmode','-synctex=1','${resource_loc}')).
```

Here I've tried without success to set an `stdin` and `stout` argument but there might be a problem under windows as pointed out there :
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2446. In the end putting the path to the file `${resource.loc}` as the last argument works well.

[image]